# Tkinter Treeview Search Does not maximize when children is searched

Tags: python-3.x, search, tkinter, treeview

# When I search 3 character keyword in Tkinter Treeview search children of #children but the children level does not maximize however when manually #maximized the children is highlighted fine. Also, searched keyword does not #scroll the window. Is there a way to do so? Please help.

```
Search when scrolled manually and maximized the level


def search(self, item=''):
    search_pattern = str(self.searchText.get())
    if len(search_pattern) < 3:
        return

    children = self.tree.get_children(item)
    for child in children:
        value_list = self.tree.item(child)["values"]
        #print(value_list)
        for i in range(len(value_list)):
            if type(value_list[0]) != int:
                if value_list[0].isprintable():
                    #print(value_list[i],'printable')
                    #if value_list[0].lower().startswith(search_pattern.lower()):
                    if value_list[0].lower().find(search_pattern.lower()) != -1:
                        self.tree.selection_set(child)
                    else:
                        res = search(self,item=child)                
        search(self,item=child)


def search_box(root):

    root.searchText = StringVar()                                       
    root.search_input = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable = root.searchText, justify = LEFT)
    root.search_input.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx=60, pady=5, sticky='NW', rowspan=2)
    print(root.search_input)
    print(root.searchText)

    root.searchText.trace_variable("w",lambda x,y,z: search(root))      # 
    Callback if stringvar is updated

    root.bind("<Return>", lambda x: hideEntry(root,x))
    root.bind("<Escape>", lambda x: hideEntry(root,x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand a branch, you can call `tree.item(iid, open=True)`.

To scroll to the place where the search is complete, you can use `tree.see(iid)`.

Combining both in your `search` method:

```
def search(self, item=''):
    search_pattern = str(self.searchText.get())
    if len(search_pattern) < 3:
        return

    children = self.tree.get_children(item)
    for child in children:
        value_list = self.tree.item(child)["values"]
        for i in range(len(value_list)):
            if type(value_list[0]) != int:
                if value_list[0].isprintable():
                    if value_list[0].lower().find(search_pattern.lower()) != -1:
                        self.tree.item(item,open=True)
                        self.tree.selection_set(child)
                        self.tree.see(child)
                    else:
                        res = search(self,item=child)                
        search(self,item=child)
```

You can read up the documentations on treeview [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview).